# How to remove index in collect array laravel withour looping

Tags: php, laravel

I have collected an array in `Laravel`, but why there is an index in result? How to remove index without iterating in loop, since if data is big, looping will take many resources.

Here is the code

```
public function test(){
        $array = [ ["no"=>1],["no"=>2] , ["no"=>3], ["no"=>4] ] ;
        $collection = collect($array);

        $filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
            return $value['no'] > 2;
        });

        return $filtered->all();
    }
```

and this is the data result

```
{
    "2": {
        "no": 3
    },
    "3": {
        "no": 4
    }
}
```

and this what my expected result

```
{
    {
        "no": 3
    },
    {
        "no": 4
    }
}
```

expected result is without index, but how to make without for each or looping, i worry if using looping will take time letter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use collection where() method

```
$array = [ ['no' => 1], ['no' => 2], ['no' => 3], ['no' => 4] ];
$collection = collect($array);

return $collection->where('no', '>', 2)->values();
```

Answer (score 6):

Call `values` on it:

```
$filtered->values()->all()
```

> "The `values` method returns a new collection with the keys reset to consecutive integers"

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `values`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values)